# Sorting ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, listview

I tried to sort my listview like this:
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-how-to-column-sorting/

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvComputers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="440" Margin="10,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="560" SelectionChanged="lvComputers_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding computerName}">
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Computername" Click="lvComputersColumnHeader_Click">Computername</GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding operatingSystem}">
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Betriebssystem" Click="lvComputersColumnHeader_Click">Betriebssystem</GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

C#:

```
private void loadComputers()
{
    lvComputers.ItemsSource = mainController.getComputers();
    lvComputers.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Computername", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvComputers.ItemsSource);
    view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Computername", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    view.Filter = UserFilter;

}

private void lvComputersColumnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewColumnHeader column = (sender as GridViewColumnHeader);
    string sortBy = column.Tag.ToString();
    if (listViewSortCol != null)
    {
        AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(listViewSortCol).Remove(listViewSortAdorner);
        lvComputers.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    }

    ListSortDirection newDir = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
    if (listViewSortCol == column && listViewSortAdorner.Direction == newDir)
        newDir = ListSortDirection.Descending;

    listViewSortCol = column;
    listViewSortAdorner = new SortAdorner(listViewSortCol, newDir);
    AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(listViewSortCol).Add(listViewSortAdorner);
    lvComputers.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(sortBy, newDir));
}
```

"getComputers" returns a list of computers based on this class:

```
public class Computers
{
    public String computerName { get; set; }
    public String operatingSystem { get; set; }
}
```

UserFilter is for a searchbox. 
But for some reason the sorting wont work.

I tried to add this

```
lvComputers.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Computername", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

to

```
loadComputers();
```

but it doesnt work either.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SortDescription` strings are case sensitive:

```
 new SortDescription("Computername", ...
```

should be

```
 new SortDescription("computerName"
```